# What are the correct steps for POST authentication to a Neo4J server?

Tags: delphi, neo4j, indy

I am trying to connect to a Neo4J sandbox, and can connect fine in the online browser. However, I'm now trying to connect via a small app. The first step is to authenticate, and no matter what I try I get '401/Unauthorized'. So far as I can tell, I am following the steps in the ["Authorization tokens" documentation](http://neo4j.com/docs/2.2.0-M02/rest-api-security.html).

With a plain HTTP connection, I am POST-ing:

- to `/authentication`
- Content-Type: `application/json`
- Accept: `application/json; charset=UTF-8`
- Accept-Charset: `UTF-8`

The payload is a JSON string: `{ "username" : "neo4j", "password" : "MYPASSWORD" }`

This is the same username and password I used to log on to the sandbox in my web browser. I have also tried setting the connection request username and password to the same values. Note there is no authentication-request response.

The full log of traffic is:

```
Send:
POST /authentication HTTP/1.0
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 91
Host: ec2-52-23-247-121.compute-1.amazonaws.com:32780
Accept: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Accept-Charset: UTF-8
Accept-Encoding: identity
User-Agent: Mozilla/3.0 (compatible; Indy Library)

Send:
%7B+%22username%22+%3A+%22neo4j%22%2C+%22password%22+%3A+%22MYPASSWORD%22+%7D
Receive:
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Date: Thu, 03 Dec 2015 20:50:11 GMT
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
WWW-Authenticate: None
Content-Length: 139
Connection: keep-alive
Server: Jetty(9.2.4.v20141103)

{
  "errors" : [ {
    "code" : "Neo.ClientError.Security.AuthorizationFailed",
    "message" : "No authorization header supplied."
  } ]
}
```

Note I have redacted my actual password in the above log.

Should the sent data have been encoded, as it has been? ('`%7B+%22username%22+...`'?) That's an automatic behaviour of the HTTP library I'm using, and I'm not familiar enough with HTTP traffic to know if it's correct or not.

So - "No authorization header supplied" seems a good hint, but the documentation does not ask for an authorization header, but says to send the username and password in JSON as the payload. Also, when I do set the request username and password, I never see the traffic communicate that.

I'm using Delphi's Indy library to communicate. The setup is very simple:a button to connection, a memo to log to, a `TIdHTTP` component on the form, and a `TIdLogStream` component to intercept the traffic (that's where the above log comes from.) All settings are defaults, except that `IdHTTP1.Intercept` is set to `IdLogStream1`.

The connection method is:

```
procedure TForm1.btnConnectClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  ParamList: TStringList;
  Res : string;
begin
  ParamList := TStringList.Create;
  try
    try
      IdHTTP1.Request.Accept := 'application/json; charset=UTF-8';
      IdHTTP1.Request.AcceptCharSet := 'UTF-8';
      IdHTTP1.Request.ContentType := 'application/json';

      ParamList.Add('{ "username" : "neo4j", "password" : "MYPASSWORD" }');
      IdHTTP1.Request.Username := 'neo4j';
      IdHTTP1.Request.Password := 'MYPASSWORD';

      Res := IdHTTP1.Post('http://ec2-52-23-247-121.compute-1.amazonaws.com:32780/authentication', ParamList);

      memData.Lines.Add(Res);
    except
      on E : Exception do
        memData.Lines.Add('Exception: ' + E.ToString);
    end;
  finally
    ParamList.Free;
  end;
end;
```

So far as I can tell, this should follow the ["Authenticate to obtain an authentication token" documentation](http://neo4j.com/docs/2.2.0-M02/rest-api-security.html#rest-api-authenticate-to-obtain-an-authorization-token). But obviously not. What am I doing wrong?

Ideally, it would be nice to have a complete set of steps for POST authentication. Authentication is a common problem in other questions here, and no solutions to those have helped me. A definitive answer of all connection steps and responses would be of great help to those who come after this question too.

**Edit:** this is Neo4J 2.3.1. It's a sandbox made via the [Neo4J Getting Started -> Sandbox](http://neo4j.com/sandbox/) page earlier today.

Comment: What version of neo4j are you using?

Comment: @cybersam Looks like 2.3.1. I've updated the question, sorry for not including that before.

Comment: OK, see my answer below.

Comment: Note that you cannot use the `TStrings` version of `TIdHTTP.Post()` to post JSON data. That version of `Post()` is intended for posting HTML webform data only, which you are not doing. You must use the `TStream` version of `Post()` instead. Put your `JSON` string into a UTF-8 encoded `TStringStream`, or use Indy's `WriteStringToStream()` function to UTF-8 encode the JSON string into a `TMemoryStream`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Very useful info, thankyou!

Answer (score 1):

The documentation you referenced was for neo4j version 2.2.0-M02. The REST API authentication mechanism changed with neo4j version 2.2.0-M04.

The documentation for 2.3.1 is [here](http://neo4j.com/docs/2.3.1/rest-api-security.html). Quote:

> Authenticate by sending a username and a password to Neo4j using HTTP
>   Basic Auth. Requests should include an Authorization header, with a
>   value of `Basic <payload>`, where "payload" is a base64 encoded string
>   of "username:password".
>
> Example request
>
> ```
> GET http://localhost:7474/user/neo4j
> Accept: application/json; charset=UTF-8
> Authorization: Basic bmVvNGo6c2VjcmV0
> ```

Comment: That looks useful, thankyou. Pity the documentation link on their site took me to the out of date one :/ It's late at night here - I'll try this tomorrow or on the weekend and update.

Comment: Hi David! What page had a link to the outdated docs? We'll fix it asap. Thanks!

Comment: FYI, `TIdHTTP` has built-in support for `Basic` authentication. Simply set the `TIdHTTP.Request.BasicAuthentication` property to true, and set `TIdHTTP.Request.Username` and `TIdHTTP.Request.Password` properties as needed.